# Schnorr NIZK Proof over Elliptic Curveの値rの計算がマイナスになってしまう

Tags: c#, 暗号理論

下記の定義を見ながら非対話ゼロ知識証明をc#で実装しています。

[RFC 8235 - Schnorr Non-interactive Zero-Knowledge Proof 日本語訳](https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc8235.html)

NIZKは、値rを計算する際に以下の数式を使用します。

```
r = v - a * c % n
```

このとき、値vは[1、n-1]の中からランダムに選んだ値を使う、と定義されていますが、例えばv=1の場合、rがマイナスの値となってしまい、必ず検証に失敗してしまいます。
secp256k1を使用して、v=2^256以上の場合、検証が成功します。

値vの選択方法が間違っているのでしょうか？
それとも、組んだプログラムに誤りがあるのでしょうか？
ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご指摘いただければ幸いです。

追記

再現コードを追加しました。

```csharp
// Use secp256k1
// the order of G
var n = BigInteger.Parse("0fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141".AsSpan(), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
// choose random a from [1, n-1]
var a = n - 50;
// choose random v from [1, n-1]
var v = new BigInteger(9876);
// hash
var c = new BigInteger(123456);

var r = v - a * c % n;

Console.WriteLine(r);
```

上記コードの出力は以下の通りです。

```
-115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518155311661
```

上記コードの計算式の計算順位を変更すると負数にはなりませんが、検証に失敗します。

```
r = (v - a * c) % n;
```

追記
私が演算子%の動きを理解していませんでした。

```
var modulus = (BigInteger a, BigInteger b) => (a % b + b) % b;

var AA = new BigInteger(-1000);
var BB = new BigInteger(3);

var x1 = AA % BB;
var x2 = modulus(AA, BB);

// x1 = -1
// x2 = 2
```

Comment: % が mod の意味なら、r は負にはならないのでは？ 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2179579

Comment: 私の演算順位が間違っているのでしょうか？サンプルコードを追加しました。